# Parent/Child Component Interaction - Return values using EventEmitter angular2

Tags: angular, eventemitter

1) I have a child component (CounterComponent) that emits an event using @Output
2) The child component also has an Input parameter callBackCancelled.
3) The parent component (AppComponent) sets the callBackCancelled value to "true" but in the child component that value is still undefined.

See the plunker sample 
https://plnkr.co/edit/2vnTUEDyBKT59GDTvkEJ

```
callbackFunction(e) {
alert('emitting event from child callback button component');
this.callback.emit(e);

alert('Now in child component, this value should be true, but it is:  ' + this.callBackCancelled);
```

}

Can someone help?

Comment: this.callBackCancelled will be true at ngOnChanges lifecycle hook.  And since you don't have Output for "callBackCancelled", you should use it so:
[callBackCancelled] without brackets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Practically, this `alert('Now in child component, this value should be true, but it is:  ' + this.callBackCancelled);` gets called before the below:

```
btncallback(event) {
    console.log(event);
    this.callBackCancelled = event;
    alert('Parent component sets the callBackCancelled value to true.');
  }
```

so by that time, `this.callBackCancelled` is still undefined. There are couple of ways to get this to work.

1. A Service
2. Implements `ngOnChanges()`

Here's an example of the latter:

1. Get rid of `()` from `[(callBackCancelled)]`
2. implements the following:https://plnkr.co/edit/qDG0dK01USbN1ifVFXvl?p=info